# Extracting links from an HTML document

Tags: html, r

I have a raw HTML file that I extract from a website (CONTR+SHIFT+I on Chrome). I now load this file into R using the following code:

```
raw-HTML <- paste(readLines("sample-site.txt"), collapse="\n")
```

I now unlist everything using this phrase

```
text <- unlist(strsplit(rawHTML, "\\."))
```

The final step I would like to take is to extract all the links that are website (so the endgoal should be a list like: https://www.google.com etc..). I try to accomplish this the following line:

```
text[grep(pattern = "href=", text, ignore.case = T)]
```

This however does not give me what I am looking for. Any feedback on what I am doing wrong and what I should do to get my desired result?

Comment: I think you should look into packages designed for HTML processing. Is web scraping a legal option?

Comment: Can you add the output of your current command? It looks like you currently just extract the "href=" part, however you need a regex that recognizes ```href="``` as the start and ```"``` as the end, extracting everything in between. So using a combination of ```str_sub()``` and ```str_locate()``` from the ```stringr``` package might help.